# VSTS Items REST API, wildcard not allowed

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get an Item from VSTS using the REST API as per [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items) documentation.

While Invoking the API from Postman I am getting the below error

> {
>       "$id": "1",
>       "innerException": null,
>       "message": "Wildcards are not allowed.",
>       "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.InvalidPathException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common",
>       "typeKey": "InvalidPathException",
>       "errorCode": 0,
>       "eventId": 0 }

API url I am trying

> https://something.visualstudio.com//DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$/Teams/Photos/Img/Hester.jpg?api-version=1.0

Comment: The parameters format is `xxx?p1=xx&p2=xx`, so your API url is incorrect, what's the result after trying my solution?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, Yes your answer helped me solve it Thanks :) Forgot to upvote, I have done it now

Answer (score 1):

using this url instead (replace `?` to `&`):

```
https://something.visualstudio.com//DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$/Teams/Photos/Img/Hester.jpg&api-version=1.0
```

or

```
https://something.visualstudio.com//DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/items/$/Teams/Photos/Img/Hester.jpg?api-version=1.0
```